# Why Intellij IDEA skips Maven test

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA version 13 on MacOS. I have a maven project, the project is stored in Git. Everything worked well.

Yesterday my Macbook crashed, then I reinstalled MacOS as well as IntelliJ IDEA. After that I checked out my project from Git and open the project in IDEA again. But now In Maven Project's Lifecycle, `test` is disabled, there a dash across `test`. I can still package my project, but "Tests are skipped".

Since my project code has no any change, I'm guessing I might miss configured something in IntelliJ IDEA. Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a skip test toggle in Maven Projects tool window.
[image: Skip Tests mode toggle]

Answer (score 0):

**To enable the maven Test, these are two steps need to complete**

**Step-1:**  Go to the settings tab, then go to Build, Execution, Deployment

**Step-2:** Then select the testing, and uncheck the Enable test runs.......